# Re-render `connect()`ed sub-component if parent's `shouldComponentUpdate`=false?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was wondering if a `connect()`ed sub-component will re-render if its parent returns `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Say, we have a component tree looking like this

```
connect(Foo extends PureComponent)
    DumbBar
        connect(Baz extends PureComponent)
```

So neither `Baz`, nor `Foo`, should re-render if their own props, supplied to them by `mapStateToProps`, keeps the same. But what happens if the state of the redux store changes and the `connect()ed` `Baz` component is notified of a state change and is supplied with new props? Will it re-render, or will the hierarchical update model of React prevent anything from rendering?

Or is this whole question perhaps a bit off, since it's not possible for a child components new rendering to take effect without affecting the ancestors - forcing the ancestors to re-render if a child changes?

If the last point is true, then putting a `connect`-ed component as a child of a `PureComponent` is lethal, as it breaks all optimizations you thought were in place, causing re-renders in other places in the sub-tree of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will re-render.

That's the whole idea of using `connect` - you don't have to pass the props and you can embed it anywhere - it will take care of keeping your component up-to-date.

Comment: But see the second question in the body: will that trigger a full re-render of the entire parent and all its other children? I guess so ...? In that case it can make your code fool you: you see a parent component be a `PureComponent` and see that its props are unchanged, so you expect no re-render, but some other coder has put a connected component into a subtree you are unaware of, breaking all your optimizations!

Comment: It will if you replace `PureComponent` with a normal one - if not, then it will see that nothing has changed. Even if your child component will re-render parent doesn't care about that.

Answer (score 1):

Each component built with `connect` will wire up it's own subscription to be notified of changes to the redux store.

So if only the props supplied to `mapStateToProps` for the child component have changed then the child component will re-render whereas the parent component will not.

You can see this yourself by adding a simple console.log to the render function.